# How to get my card memory reader to work?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I have a Asus K55vd laptop and the build-in 'Realtek PCIE CardReader' (RTL8411) doesn't work.

This is what I've done for two driver versions.  I've uninstalled the driver, rebooted my system, installed the driver again, rebooted my system again and then tried to read a SDHC memory card.

The drivers I've tried are the one of the Asus website and the other came from the Realtek website. I've Windows 7 64 installed.

In my device manager I don't have any yellow warnings. The device manager shows a node 'Memory technlogy driver' with a child node 'Realtek PCIE CardReader'. It seems that this looks okay, but I still can't read any cards.

What else can I try to get my card reader to work?

Comment: Asus technical spec only says "2 -in-1 card reader ( SD/ MMC)". They do not say that the Card Reader is SDHC capable. Did you try with a SD (not SDHC) Card?

Comment: @Martijn - Does your Memory Card Reader even support SDHC memory cards?

Comment: @Ramhound + Werner Henze: It seems that Card Reader doesn't read SDHC cards at all. Thanks for your suggestions.